# How to Pronounce Cars and Says?

Tags: pronunciation

I think for a pronunciation symbol, cars is **/kɑːrz/** and says is **/seɪz/**.

But whenever I listen these words I feel like there are a little “d” sound, **Cars /kɑːrdz/** and **Says/seɪdz/.**

For me, cars sound like cards and says sounds like saids.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Minimal pair: *wards* `/wɔrdz/` and *wars* `/wɔrz/`

Comment: Thanks snailboat. Oh!Minimal pair, it's so interesting to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the pronunciation you used in your first sentence is the correct one.

cars is like "carz" and says is like "sez". No D sounds.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "d" consonant in these words. If a "d" sound is inserted into "cars" it becomes "cards". If someone is referring to a plurality of automobiles, and you're distinctly hearing "cards", that person is making a mistake or has some kind of speech impairment.

Your pronunciation notation appears questionable. Let's look at "cars". It depends on dialect. If you're in Britain, it is /kɑːz/. In the predominant dialect spoken in North America, /ka:rz/.

/seɪz/ is incorrect; that notation follows the pronunciation pattern of "days" /deɪz/.  Unlike in "days", in the written form of "says", the letters "ay" do not denote a dipthong; the pronunication is just /sez/.

"Say" is /seɪ/, of course, but the third person inflection is not formed simply by adding /z/.

The "says" part of "essays" is pronounced /seɪz/, but that is not related to "say".

I can hardly think of any other place in the spelling of the language where "ays" goes to /ez/. Other than in "says", it "ay" corresponds to /eɪ/ except in certain words like "papaya" and "picayune" which are of a completely different formation. Let's not forget the troublesome "quay" which sounds exactly like "key" (except to some North Americans). So, good news: "says" may be the only example of its kind that you have to memorize.

There is no word /seɪz/, and if we add a /d/ to make /seɪdz/, that is also not a word; however, there exist surnames Seyds and Seyd.

Answer (score 2):

In British English (BrE) the pronunciation of *car* is [**/kɑː/**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/cars#car__4)
 The plural form, *cars*, in AmE is pronounced: [**/kɑːrz/**](http://www.pronouncehow.com/english/cars_pronunciation)

You can hear a British person pronouncing the word *cars* in a series of other words ending with the letters *ars* [here](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/media/drills/01%20Famous%20Stars%20Smoke%20Cigars.mp3) and by a different speaker, [here](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=cars).

The verb *say* is always pronounced [**/seɪ/**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/say) the third person singular form, *says*, is usually pronounced as **/sez/**.

Click on the links to hear how these words are pronounced.